# Which of these 2 MongoDB design choices is recommended?

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I have 2 models: `Supplier` and `Supplier type`. The client should be able to retrieve all `Suppliers` belonging to a particular `Supplier Type`:

`Supplier`:

```
name: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
    minlength: 2,
    maxlength: 255,
  },
  ...
supplier_type: { type: ObjectId, ref: 'SupplierType' },
}
```

`SupplierType`:

```
name: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
    minlength: 2,
    maxlength: 50,
  },
suppliers: [{ type: ObjectId, ref: 'Supplier' }],
};
```

Design 1:

- A field on `Supplier` contains a reference to the assigned `Supplier Type` object.
- An array on the `Supplier Type` object contains object references to all the `Suppliers` that have the Supplier Type.
- The client queries the relevant `Supplier Type` document, let's say `Vegetables` and contained in the response, among other fields, will be a list of `Suppliers`.

With this approach, each time a new Supplier is saved, at least one other DB operation would be needed to update the `Suppliers` array on the `Supplier Type` object.

Design 2:

- Remove the `Suppliers` reference array from `Supplier Type` object
- A field on `Supplier` contains a reference to the assigned `Supplier Type` object, as in design 1.
- The Client, this time, queries the `Supplier` document with a parameter specifying the `Supplier Type` i.e. GET `/suppliers?supplier-type=Vegetables`

Which design makes the most sense/would be the recommended approach in MongoDB?

Comment: I usually find that most of these `is option A or option B better` type of questions are usually answered with, It really depends a lot on your data and what kind of queries you expect to be doing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see no reason to split these two objects into separate collections. Embed the `SupplierType` inside the `Supplier` object. If a `Supplier` can be of more than one `SupplyType` you can extend that object into an array.

Now when you get any `Supplier` you automatically get their `SupplierType` without the need for a join and/or a second query.

Want to find all the `Supplier` docs by `SupplyType`? Query on the `SupplyType` field and a single cursor will return all the relevant suppliers.

Apply indexes to either field if the number of items is large to improve performance.

Comment: Thanks for the input, Joe. If I were to drop the `SupplierType`  collection, what would be the best way to retrieve a list of all Supplier Types in that case?

Comment: Run a https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.distinct/ (distinct) query on the SupplierType field.